# How to do a conditional where clause with where in PL/SQL within Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a pretty simple Stored Procedure that I am in trouble to do because i'm new to SQL and PL/SQL. I Have a table with a name column that is a varchar(55).

I discovered that if the user executes my procedure with an empty string as a paramter the LIKE statment brings all rows from TABLE1

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE COLUMN LIKE VARIABLE || '%'
AND...
```

So I tried to change the query so if the VARIABLE is passed with a empty string it can still perform other conditions in the where statment.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE (VARIABLE <> '' AND COLUMN LIKE VARIABLE || '%')
AND...
```

But now wherever I pass as variable ('', NULL, 'anystring') I get no rows returned.

How can I build a query that validates if the variable is different of empty string and if it is it performs the LIKE statment with the variable correctly?

Comment: `WHERE (VARIABLE IS NULL OR COLUMN LIKE VARIABLE || '%') AND...`

Comment: Now the query always returns value even with '' as paramter

Comment: I removed the "AND" statment and now I tested with only the LIKE statment...same result. Return all rows

Comment: `WHERE ((VARIABLE = '' OR VARIABLE IS NULL) AND VARIABLE || '%')`

Comment: @jelliaes Now if pass value to variable it returns zero rows and if do not pass it returns all values...

=( Did not thought this thing as this difficult to do

Comment: @jelliaes, note that in Oracle, `VARIABLE = ''` always evaluates to unknown because `''` is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it is not difficult thing to do. You can use conditional WHERE clause using [CASE WHEN](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php). So your query will support different scenarios, something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE (CASE WHEN variable IS NULL AND column IS NULL THEN 1
            WHEN variable LIKE '%' AND column LIKE variable||'%' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END) = 1
AND...
```

Basically, it checks if the `variable = ''` then it will compare the column against `''`. Otherwise, it will compare it against `variable||'%'`.

Notice, Oracle treats empty string of the type VARCHAR as NULL (this does not apply to CHAR). So, in the first scenario we compare against NULL.

Comment: this did not return any values either way =(

Comment: @MarcosSantini I updated the query. It is tested, and it should be working

Comment: Why don't just `WHERE variable IS NULL AND column IS NULL  OR variable LIKE '%' AND column LIKE variable||'%'` ? It's simpler, shorter and doesn't prevent Oracle from doing some optimizations like OR expansion => https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_transform.htm#GUID-0D5B9093-CDEA-45AC-A607-1F0D8F2615DD  while your query must always do a full table scan and aplly the CASE expresiion on all records, one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Just a thought for this we can use Dynamic sql too. If you may try this approach. Hope it helps.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SPS_TEST_OUT(
    p_input_in IN VARCHAR2
    )
AS
  lv_sql LONG;
  lv_where VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  lv_where:= CASE WHEN p_input_in IS NULL OR p_input_in = '' THEN 
              ''
             ELSE 
            ' AND COLUMN1 LIKE '''||p_input_in||'''%' 
             END;
  lv_sql:='SELECT * FROM TABLE
            WHERE 1 = 1 
          ' ||lv_where;
  dbms_output.put_line(lv_sql);
END;
```